# Some web page links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello am using the Twitter-Bootstrap framework to develop a website for a client but I have  hit a wall and I don't know what may be causing It. Before I go any further I will throw in my html and css code then explain the problem.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

/* TOP OF THE PAGE */
#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.top-social {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-social a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.top-social ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-social ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.top-social ul li.last {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.top-social ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-social a.email {
  font-weight: 400;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

strong.logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 0;
}

strong.logo a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.book-section {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.number-box {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.number-box span {
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.number-box strong {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
  display: block;
}

div.btn-book-box {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
}

div.btn-book-box a.btn-book {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9bc83c;
}

div.btn-book-box a.btn-book:hover {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  color: #222;
}

/*.navigation*/ .navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
}

/*.navigation */.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

/*.navigation */.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.nav-outer {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="topbar-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="top-social">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="mailto:" class="email" title="Send us an email">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> info@prideafricasafaris.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="logo-section">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <strong class="logo"><a href="#">Pride Africa Safaris</a>       </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="book-section">
                    <div class="number-box">
                        <div class="number-text">
                            <span>Call us for any Query</span>
                            <strong><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +256 7** 5** 6**</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-book-box">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-book">Book Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-outer">
                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Since now you have seen my code, The problem is when I include the div with the class navigation, the links within the top-social and logo-section divs remain static and non-reactive but when I remove the div with the class navigation, everything seems to work normally, what could be the issue here? Thanks In advance.

Comment: Sounds like a script related problem ... no script shown

Comment: @charlietfl, i have not even created any script yet, am just using the default jquery and bootstrap js files

Comment: define `non reactive` and `remain static`

Comment: @charlietfl, i mean you can't click the link and the links don't react to anything event like hovering or mouseover

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co or codepen that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d9rpvkpg/) to the fiddle that i have made

Comment: So what should I see or do in demo to understand issue?

Comment: @charlietfl, i thought when you would see the live demo of what is typed above, may be you could probably see the problem is and try the finc the solution using that

Comment: Never seen your page or know what you expect it to do or not do compared to what it currently does. No not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you floating all your sections? They are floating over each other right now.

Remove the `float` property from your `topbar-section` div, your `top-social` div as well as your `logo-section` div and the elements will be clickable again.

Example for `topbar-section`:

```
.topbar-section {
    float: left; <<-- REMOVE THIS
    width: 100%; <<-- REMOVE THIS TOO
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/d9rpvkpg/3/

---

Also, I noticed that you're using `float` on certain other elements in your fiddle too. Remove them and keep only the one's which are necessary.

Do read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float to understand how float works.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I noticed you're floating other items too in your fiddle. I would recommend removing them too. Keep only the one's which are really necessary.

Comment: Sorry i have taken so long to respond @@Andrew Lyndem but you are a life saver. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take

```
float: left;
```

out of .topbar-section

Why do the parent elements have float: left?